# Get timezone always with Daylight time saving On in Java even if Systems Daylight option is unchecked in java

Tags: java, windows, timezone, dst

I am trying to read a `Timezone` in Java using

```
String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getId();
```

It gives me the proper `Timezone` if daylight saving time is enabled but if it is disabled it gives me the result in GMT. I expect to not get GMT, independent of system settings.

Is there a way in Java to always get the results of DST as ON?

**For e.g**
Goto Systems(Windows) - > ChangeDateandTimeSettings -> Change Timezone - > Set Timezoene to UTC+00:00 Dublin,Edinburg,Lisbon,London now run the above code with Automatically Adjust Sytems time as checked you get the result **"Europe/London"** now disable the checkbox you get the result as **GMT** , In both the cases I want the result as **Europe/London**

Comment: What exactly do you call "enable/disable" DST? What actions do you carry, very very precisely, to disable DST in Java?

Comment: Like if we try to change Time zone of a Sytem using Change date and time, there we get a option to Auto Adjust System timing as per Daylight .

Comment: Does your time zone happen to coincide with GMT during the standard time part of the year? Which is your time zone?

Comment: I said, "very very precisely". I meant, very very precisely. Describe where you click and what you type. Screenshots may be helpful

Comment: (1) I cannot reproduce. I set my default time zone to Africa/Mogadishu and your code gave me — Africa/Mogadishu, no mention of DST. I then set it to America/Santiago and got America/Santiago. (2) Why do you want to get DST always on? What sense would that make? (3) Please post compliable code. I got “The method getId() is undefined for the type TimeZone”.

Comment: Goto ChangeDateandTimeSettings -> Change Timezone - > Set Timezoene to UTC+00:00 Dublin,Edinburg,Lisbon,London  now run the above code with Automatically Adjust Sytems time as checked you get the result **"Europe/London"** now disable the checkbox you get the result as **"GMT"** , In both the cases I want the result as  **"Europe/London"**

Comment: "ChangeDateandTimeSettings"? Honestly, at this point I cannot imagine that you don't understand that I'm asking you to explain clearly what you're doing. You are just refusing to express yourself clearly.

Comment: Change Date and Time Settings, is that something in your operating system? It doesn’t seem to work exactly that way in mine, so you may want to edit your question and add an explanation, including which OS you’re using if this is relevant.

Comment: @kumesana : I have clearly mentioned all the steps with the problem I am facing and what is my expected solutions can you let me know what in the question needs to be more elaborated

Comment: It's just you could be clearer. "Systems(windows)" doesn't mean anything. You could say "This is on Windows OS. I start the Windows program called System (click Windows start menu, type System in the programs search bar)". There is no such thing as "ChangeDateandTimeSettings". You could have said "go to Control Panel in the navigation bar, then in menu Clock, Language, and Region, then option Change the time zone"

Comment: Anyway from what I gathered, it seems that disabling DST adjustment modifies the way Windows advertises about time and time zones, and programs won't be able to detect it the same way as before. Java in particular, won't see the time zone as it is described in the "Change time zone" menu, and instead will only see the offset from UTC. Which, by the way, is correct, because the time zone Europe/London does apply DST. If something doesn't apply DST, then it is not Europe/London. It is something else.

Comment: "In both the cases I want the result as Europe/London" - but then you wouldn't actually be seeing the time zone that the system is observing. Europe/London has a specific meaning in the IANA database, and that includes DST. When you disable DST, you're effectively saying "I don't want to use normal time zone rules" - so your system is no longer in the Europe/London zone, effectively. Java is correctly representing the system time zone. (Well, sort of. If the time zone changes standard time, I'm not sure how that even *should* be handled...)

Answer (score -1):

May be you can try getting the number of days in a certain period.

The below method finds the number of days between the period start date to the period end date. This means that the start date is counted as a days within the period, but not the end date. For example, January 01 to January 10th includes 9 days total. This method takes into account daylight savings time to ensure that days are counted correctly across DST boundaries.

For example,

```
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

// …

    public int getDaysInPeriod() {

        final LocalDate start;
        final LocalDate end;
        final int daysInCycle;


        if (end.isBefore(start) || end.isEqual(start)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Is that just me? I fail to see the connection between the question and this answer.